# This was a fad in the 1950s. What was it called?

Tags: single-word-requests

You kept this large plastic ring circling around your waist by moving your hips.  It became very popular overnight and most teenagers got one.  I was very young at the time and I can't remember its name, and I haven't seen any in a long time.

Comment: @Centaurus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hula_hoop

Comment: Gyrations associated with **She Wears Red Feathers**  written by Bob Merrill in 1952; lyrics  "She Wears Red Feathers and a Hula-Hula Skirt."

Comment: "large plastic ring circling around your waist". They have rattan ones too, you know. I had rattan ones, before plastic became popular. I think in the 50s, they were mainly rattan rather than plastic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Hula-Hoop***  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hula_hoop)

I remember it too.  I knew people who were experts, but the #$%@ thing always fell around my ankles after a few twirls.

> A hula hoop is a toy hoop that is twirled around the waist, limbs or
>   neck. The modern hula hoop was invented in 1958 by Arthur K. "Spud"
>   Melin and Richard Knerr, but children and adults around the world have
>   played with hoops, twirling, rolling and throwing them throughout
>   history. Hula hoops for children generally measure approximately 71
>   centimetres (28 in) in diameter, and those for adults around 1.02
>   metres (40 in). Traditional materials for hoops include willow, rattan
>   (a flexible and strong vine), grapevines and stiff grasses. Today,
>   they are usually made of plastic tubing.

The Wikipedia article has a 1958 picture of a girl hula-hooping.

Comment: I attended the national hula hoop contest, sometime in the 50's, not as a competitor.  1958 sounds a little late -- I was a junior in high school then.  The contest was sponsored by Art Linkletter (remember him? "Kids say the darndest things"), who presumably had invested in hula hoops.  Some of the girl contestants could do incredible things with their hips.  Takes me back.

Comment: @Greg Lee -- I agree, thinking it over, 1958 seems late. I'll google a bit more.

Comment: @Greg Lee -- Wham-O introduced the hula-hoop in 1958 and it quickly went viral.

Answer (score 2):

The device you refer to is known as a "[hoola hoop](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hula_hoop)."